# What is the difference between global and local happiness?

Tags: civilization-5, civilization-5-gods-and-kings

In Civilization V some buildings or policies affect local happiness, while others global. What's the difference? I understand local means per city, but does it have any different effects towards the total happiness of your empire than global does?

Comment: See: http://civilization.wikia.com/wiki/Happiness_%28Civ5%29

Comment: http://gaming.stackexchange.com/a/155197/1057

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Local happiness is the same value as global happiness but is capped by population. So if you have 6 possible local happiness in a city from buildings, but the city is only 5 population, you only receive 5 happiness. When your city increases to 6 then you will have 6 local happiness in the city. This prevents a city from providing positive happiness

Comment: The reasoning behind the local/global happiness split is to prevent Infinite City Spam: building a large number of tiny cities to take advantage of per-city bonuses, and a small number of huge cities to get the real work done. Since cities can't provide net-positive happiness, this puts a dent in Infinite City Spam.

Comment: @PaulMarshall Of course, it doesn't actually work very well. Infinite city spam was killed by the science penalty per city that was patched in combined with the heavy push toward support for tall civilizations via policies, not by happiness limitations. Its easy to take certain policies and ICS while remaining happy-neutral but it can really hurt you instead of helping.